# Ionic 5 React Firebase auth phone number IOS Fail

Tags: ios, reactjs, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication

Hello I try create connection with phoneNumber with Firebase.
On Android OS all OK but with iOS I have auth/internal-error.
I trie to put GoogleService-info on Xcode but nothing work

code:

```
import { initializeApp } from “firebase/app”;
import {
getAuth,
signInWithPhoneNumber,
} from “firebase/auth”;
initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const auth = getAuth();
signInWithPhoneNumber(
auth,
formatPhoneNumberFirebase(phoneNumber),
recaptchaVerifier
)
.then((confirm) => {
confirmationResult = confirm;
resolve();
})
.catch((error) => console.error(error));
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: @KyleAbens i use firebase-x, https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/firebase-x